# Error reading webpack-stats.json. Are you sure webpack has generated the file and the path is correct?

Tags: django, vue.js, npm, webpack, vuejs3

I installed django with Vue and got this eror in runtime:

```
Error reading webpack-stats.json. Are you sure webpack has generated the file and the path is correct?
```

[image]

alongside manage.py:

```
vue create frontend
```

Default ([Vue 3] babel, eslint)

```
cd frontend
npm run serve
```

list of files in frontend directory is:

```
babel.config.js
jsconfig.json
node_modules
package.json
package-lock.json
public
README.md
src
vue.config.js


npm --version
```

6.14.15

```
nodejs --version
```

v10.19.0

```
node --version
```

v14.17.6

```
npm list webpack-bundle-tracker
```

└── webpack-bundle-tracker@1.5.0

```
pip install django-webpack-loader
pip freeze
```

django-webpack-loader==1.5.0

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
  ...
  'webpack_loader',
  ...
)


# vue.config.js
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')
module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: true
})
```

index.html

```
{% load render_bundle from webpack_loader %}
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title></title>    

    {% render_bundle 'app' 'css' %}
  </head>
  <body>
            <div class="main">
                <main>
                  <div id="app">
                    
                  </div>
                    {% endblock %}
                </main>
            </div>
    {% render_bundle 'app' 'js' %}
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello @namjoo, are permissions set correctly ? you can view it with`ls -l`, the user running your server might not have right permissions to read/write files.

Comment: Hello @Gwendal . Thanks. Yes all permissions set properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import and add the `webpack-bundle-tracker` plugin in `vue.config.js`:

```
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')
const BundleTracker = require('webpack-bundle-tracker')

module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: true,
  configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [
      new BundleTracker({ path: __dirname, filename: 'webpack-stats.json' }),
    ],
  },
})
```

Comment: I think I get this error since I have an error with vuejs. **options has an unknown property 'watchOptions'.**

Answer (score 2):

```
vue.config.js


const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')
const BundleTracker = require('webpack-bundle-tracker')

module.exports = defineConfig({
  publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? '/static/dist/' : 'http://localhost:8080',
  outputDir: '../static/dist',
  indexPath: '../templates/index.html',
  transpileDependencies: true,
  configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [
      new BundleTracker({ path: __dirname, filename: 'webpack-stats.json' }),
    ],
  },
})
```

files structure are:

```
mainapp/
frontend/
   vue.gonfig.js
   package.json
   webpack-stats.json
static/
template/
manage.py
```

also i run `npm run build` before `npm run serve`

settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS=[
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'assets')
]

WEBPACK_LOADER = {
  'DEFAULT': {
    'CACHE': not DEBUG,
    'BUNDLE_DIR_NAME': '/bundles/',
    'STATS_FILE': os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'frontend', 'webpack-stats.json'),
    'POLL_INTERVAL': 0.1,
    'IGNORE': [r'.+\.hot-update.js', r'.+\.map'],
  }
}
```